# how to union multiple columns from one panda data frame into one series?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sklearn-pandas

I have a data frame that has actually more than 20 columns. The example below give 4 columns. each column has equal number of rows.   How to convert to a new dataframe(exmaple shown below) which has only one columns. I will use the new combined dataframe to calculate some metrics. How do I write a neat and efficient code for this?  Thank you so much!

[image]

```
data={"col1":[1,2,3,5], "col_2":[6,7,8,9], "col_3":[10,11,12,14], "col_4":[7,8,9,10]}
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you start from your dictionary, use [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain):

```
data={"col1":[1,2,3,5], "col_2":[6,7,8,9], "col_3":[10,11,12,14], "col_4":[7,8,9,10]}

from itertools import chain
pd.DataFrame({'col': chain.from_iterable(data.values())})
```

Else, [`ravel`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.ravel.html) the underlying numpy array:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
pd.Series(df.to_numpy().ravel('F'))
```

Output:

```
0      1
1      2
2      3
3      5
4      6
5      7
6      8
7      9
8     10
9     11
10    12
11    14
12     7
13     8
14     9
15    10
dtype: int64
```

Depending on the computation to perform, you might not even need to instantiate a DataFrame/Series and stick to the array:

```
a = df.to_numpy().ravel('F')
```

Output: `array([ 1,  2,  3,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 14,  7,  8,  9, 10])`

Answer (score 2):

You can convert the DataFrame to a numpy array and flatten it using the [`ravel`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.ravel.html) method. Finally, construct a Series (or a DataFrame) with the result.

```
data = {"col1":[1,2,3,5], "col_2":[6,7,8,9], "col_3":[10,11,12,14], "col_4":[7,8,9,10]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

new_col = pd.Series(df.to_numpy().ravel(order='F'), name='new_col')
```

Output:

```
>>> new_col

0      1
1      2
2      3
3      5
4      6
5      7
6      8
7      9
8     10
9     11
10    12
11    14
12     7
13     8
14     9
15    10
Name: new_col, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with `melt`

```
out = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data).melt().drop(['variable'],axis=1)
Out[109]: 
    value
0       1
1       2
2       3
3       5
4       6
5       7
6       8
7       9
8      10
9      11
10     12
11     14
12      7
13      8
14      9
15     10
```